# Excel Macro Sum of a Row

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sum of row, stop when the first result is positive. The rest of the row values will be converted/replaced with 0, and the last with positive result will have the final sum.

Eg.

Row A1:F1 = -2, -3, -6, 6, 20, 2

Will have:

Row = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 17

EDIT: In my dirty solution (formula), i have these:

For each row in A2:F2

A2 =IF(SUM(A1:A1)<0,0,A1)

B2 =IF(SUM(A1:B1)<0,0,SUM(A1:B1))

C2 =IF(SUM(A1:C1)<0,0,SUM(A1:C1))

D2 =IF(SUM(A1:D1)<0,0,SUM(A1:D1))

E2 =IF(SUM(A1:E1)<0,0,SUM(A1:E1))

F2 =IF(SUM(A1:F1)<0,0,SUM(A1:F1))

But it should stop evaluating when it hits the first positive sum from the array.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Do you think we're a script writing service? If so, I think you're mistaken. Please show what you've tried yourself so we can see where things have gone wrong and then we can help

Comment: Sorry have not tried anything yet. I can do formula but not in macro.

Comment: Then use the formula

Comment: If you are asking how to make a formula into a macro, then [edit] your question to ask that. Include the formula you are already using. At least it will show some effort on your part. As @DaveRook already stated, we are not a script writing service, so you are going to have to show some effort.

Comment: Is "Row = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 17" not the expected output? If not, what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Output must be

Row = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, value as is, value as is, ...

See my post below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done without VBA (always the better solution!). If your data is in row A, try putting this in B1: `=IF(SUM($A$1:A1)<0;0;SUM($A$1:A1))` and copy-past to the right.

Ps: Not sure what should be in the cells right of the cell where the sum is. Right now, it keeps adding those values. Please edit your question if this should work different.

Comment: I had written similar formula, basically creating redundant for equivalent number of columns for each row. So if I had 6 data in a row, I make 6 equivalent rows on the right just to test if the SUM is > 0. But it is ugly and ineffective if you have unknown number of rows to analyze. Thank you

Comment: @CharlieRB: because using VBA tricks people into building applications on a platform that isn't ultimately meant for that purpose, resulting in erroneous/faulty behavior of the application, resulting in bad decisions and lots of debugging. For example in the OP's question: one or more rows of data? What offset of the resulting data? Protection to overwrite existing data? etc. Other arguments  can be found for example [here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348928/pros-and-cons-of-vb-vba) .

Comment: Good deal. I'll clean up my comments to reduce clutter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to attain it without macro by adding additional "IF" statement. The output should be:

Given row A1:F1 = -2, -3, -6, 6, 20, 2

Output Row A2:F2 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 2

Will stop at the first positive SUM result.

.

So the formula became very long, and not a good solution. I can use this for now, but if anyone can share a macro, I would really appreciate it.

For rows A2:F2

A2=IF(SUM(A1:A1)<0,0,A1)

B2=IF(SUM(A1:B1)<0,0,IF(A1>0,B1,SUM(A1:B1)))

C2=IF(SUM(A1:C1)<0,0,IF(B3>0,C1,SUM(A1:C1)))

D2=IF(SUM(A1:D1)<0,0,IF(C3>0,D1,SUM(A1:D1)))

E2=IF(SUM(A1:E1)<0,0,IF(D3>0,E1,SUM(A1:E1)))

F2=IF(SUM(A1:F1)<0,0,IF(E3>0,F1,SUM(A1:F1)))

.

Again thanks everyone for your thoughts